# Store data only until user quits electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

In electron, is there any way to store data only until the app is quit? If I'm not mistaken, session storage is persisted across restarts, right?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32950922/15842737 - Also, no. Session storage is for the session, I think you might be looking for localStorage instead

Comment: @savageGoat So sessionStorage isn't persisted after exit?

Comment: @Jake what exactly are you storing?

Comment: @jake no, sessionStorage exipres when the program closes. I searched it for you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persisting-data-in-electronjs/