# How to capture the window close event on Electron's renderer process?

Tags: javascript, electron, renderer

On a classic front-end JavaScript, capturing the "window close" event can be done in a multiple ways. It can be done with:

```js
// Method A: `close` event via an event listener
window.addEventListener( 'close', function(event){ /** your magic here **/ } )

// Method B: `beforeunload` event via an event listener
window.addEventListener( 'beforeunload', function(event){ /** your magic here **/ } )

// Method C: classic `onclose` event binder
window.onclose = function(event){ /** your magic here **/ }

// Method D: classic `onbeforeunload` event binder
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){ /** your magic here **/ }
```

I tried these methods inside the Electron's `renderer` script/environment but the window close event doesn't seem to get triggered.

Which brings to my question, how to capture the "window close" event on Electron's renderer process?

Comment: According to [this question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885657/how-to-catch-the-event-of-clicking-the-app-windows-close-button-in-electron-app), the suggested method was to use the Browser API's `close` event as you pointed out yourself. I do not understand why it is not being triggered by your application.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen the accepted answer from that post was using the `main` process of Electron. It was not clearly stated though on that thread. So it is a different topic. This question however is with using the `renderer` process of Electron.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Electron's official documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app):

> **Event: "before-quit"** Emitted before the application starts closing its windows. Calling event.preventDefault() will prevent the default behavior, which is terminating the application.

So you need to use the `before-quit` event on your Electron application.

Comment: This method uses the `main` process of Electron. The hint from that link is that it uses the `app` object which can only be accessed from the `main` process. Thus, would not work on the `renderer` process.

Comment: I am really not a good programmer, I am just google searching on your behalf. So please forgive my mistakes. However, according to my searches [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) can help communicate between renderer process and main process.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, proving that these events trigger (or not) is difficult as the render process would normally close prior to confirmation.

Instead, through the use of [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc), one can tell if any of these events trigger by sending one or more messages back to the main process for viewing.

To test this, I have implemented a simple `preload.js`, `main.js` and `index.html` script.

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'ipcRender', {
        send: (message) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('closing', message);
        }
    });
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// Testing
electronIpcMain.on('closing', (event, message) => {
    console.log(message);
})
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Close">
    </body>

    <script>
        // Method A: `close` event via an event listener
        window.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
            window.ipcRender.send('Method A'); // Doesn't work
        })

        // Method B: `beforeunload` event via an event listener
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
            window.ipcRender.send('Method B'); // Works
        })

        // Method C: classic `onclose` event binder
        window.onclose = (event) => {
            window.ipcRender.send('Method C'); // Doesn't work
        }

        // Method D: classic `onbeforeunload` event binder
        window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
            window.ipcRender.send('Method D'); // Works
        }

        // Method E: `click' event via an event listener
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Let's pretent that this can close the window from the main process
            window.ipcRender.send('Method E');
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

Below is the result when closed via the **traffic light** close button or the **task bar** close menu.

```js
Method B // `beforeunload` event via an event listener
Method D // classic `onbeforeunload` event binder
```

---

Depending on how one (correctly or incorrectly) implements their `preload.js` script, one may receive no results compared to the results shown above.

> Whilst I usually implement my `preload.js` script differently to that shown above, I have kept it simple and inline with what most people appear to be familiar with. IE: [`Context Isolation (Enabled)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#after-context-isolation-enabled)